# How to pass a variable from view to filter class in django?

Tags: python, django, variables, filter, django-filter

I want to pass a variable from my view to a class filter. I'm new in Python/Django and I don't have idea how it works.

This is my class in views.py

```
def index(request=None):
    f = pfTransFilter(request.GET, queryset=trans_query, _USER = request.user)
```

This is my filters.py

```
class pfTransFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
       trans_token = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Token.objects.filter(user=_USER.id))
```

Well, I want to pass user to my filter class to make something like this **user=_USER.id** But I don't know how to...

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try `user=request.user.id`, does that give you any errors?